# Is there a difference between combining two fans in parallel and buying one with twice as much CFM?

Tags: air-quality, air

I want to build something like an "air purifier". I'm considering a box where I have a big filter and I send the air from one side to the other.

I want to maximize the air flow through the box trying to filter the air in the room.

I have access to many cheap computer fans which would move around 50 CFM. I want to achieve at least around 200 CFM.

Is there any difference in the final CFM if I use 4 or 6 of these fans making a grid of 2x2 or 2x3 compared to using a larger fan which in my scenario is harder to get?

Answer (score 1):

1. Noise. Depending on fan make, more small fans = less noise.
2. Pressure. Depending on fan type, you might not get the rated CFM. Computer chassis fans might be optimized for airflow and do not handle obstructions well, on the other hand, the heatsink fans (cpu) usually handle pressure well, because they are meant for blowing through tiny fins.

If you have fans lying around, just try it.

Answer (score 0):

In free air, which is the environment these fans are meant to be used in, the CFM would be the same. The problem will arise with the higher pressure inside the box when the fans are running which will be needed to force air through the filter. The small computer fans might not be strong enough to move the air efficiently. A larger, stronger fan might be your best bet.

Comment: More to the point, a fan of a **completely different design** (squirrel cage - some computer fans, but not many, are built that way) does much better with back pressure than axial fans (the de-facto standard "computer fan")

Comment: Would stacking two fans solve this issue (series not parallel)?

Answer (score 0):

The airflow of a fan depends on how much pressure it has to "push" against.

Some fan designs are optimized for high flow at low pressure, like PC fans.

Other fan designs are optimized for higher pressure.

Depending on how much pressure your filter needs to get air through it, a low pressure fan like a PC fan might not get any useful flow at all.

For this use case you'd need something more like a HVAC fan, that can push a lot of air through pipes while not making too much noise. It looks like that. The fan in my HEPA air purifier has the same design.

[image]

Note you can get HEPA air purifiers for something like €100, so it may not be worth the trouble...